# Вывод в n-ой системе счисления, с помощью рекурсии

Tags: c, системы-счисления

Скажите пожалуйста, почему у меня число `82345` в 12-ой системе равно `101A9`, а не `3B7A1` и как исправить?

```
#define DIG "0123456789ABCDEF"

int n=0;

void writetoP(int p, unsigned a){
    if(a){
        writetoP(p, a>>4);
        printf("%c",DIG[a&(p-1)]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int p,n;
    scanf("%i %i",&p,&n);
    writetoP(p,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Именно двенадцатеричной?

Comment: Вообще по условию дано натуральное число n в p-ой системе (1<p<=16). И нужно вывести число n в системе счисления с основанием p.

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy так а как оно дано-то? А то звучит так, как будто вам просто нужно считать строку (n в p-ой системе) и вывести эту строку (тоже n в p-ой системе).

Comment: А что вы делаете? берете 4 бита (т.е. от 0 до 15) и пытаетесь что-то из этого получить (не соображу, что, но это уже просто неважно...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы что-то подобное реализовать пытаетесь?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

void prnt(long number, int base) {
    if (!number) return;
    prnt(number / base, base);
    printf("%c", digits[number % base]);
}

int main() {
    prnt(82345, 12);
}
```

Откуда у вас какие-то странные шифты на 4 бита?
И почему `#define`, а не массив `char`?

(Имена `number` и `base` для наглядности).

**Принцип:**

Как меня учили в школе, самый младший разряд числа `n` с основанием `p` можно получить, взяв остаток от деления `n` на `p` (`n % p`). А потом сдвигаем это число на один разряд (`n / p`) (как будто аккуратно достаем самый нижний кубик башенки).

**Дополнение**

Кажется понял, что вы пытались сделать у себя в примере. Шифт на 4 бита и `(a & (p - 1))` - так у вас все будет работать, да, но вот только до тех пор, **пока вы не используете основание, отличное от 16**. Шифт на 4 бита - по сути деление на 16. 16 - 1 по основанию два, как известно, будет `1111`, и `1111 & вашеЧисло` даст не что иное, как остаток от деления этого числа на 16.

В моем примере я сделал вариант (хоть и чуть более медленный), работающий с любыми основаниями.